# Troubleshoot packet loss and slow transfers on some sites

Tags: ping, networking, mtr

I need some help troubleshooting a network problem. Home ISP says its the server's network to blame, and host says there's problem on ISP side. With little knowledge, its hard to see where the problem is.

Problem is, there's a lot of packet loss and file transfer speeds go down to less than 100Kb/s.

Following is what I have noticed:

- There's no problem connecting to majority of the websites, no drops,
  speed remains stable (~3Mb/s). Problem only occurs with my server and
  a handful of other sites (not the same region/location as my site).
- Using a different ISP, I can connect properly to my server without
  any problems.

What I am confused about is, if its my ISP's problem, I can connect to almost every other site out there (facebook,youtube,etc) without any problems. Hell, I can even connect without problems to a different data center that is located in the same region as my server.

If its my Host's problem, I can connect without any issues if I use a different ISP.

Would really appreciate if someone could help me pinpoint the problem so I can make my complaints convincingly.

[image: MTR Report (To/Reverse)]

Comment: More info needed around the setup. I'm going to guess that you're trying to connect from a web browser on your home network to a web server in a datacentre somewhere, and having troubles. When you use a "different ISP", is there anything else different?  Host type, host O/S, connection type, etc?

Comment: @DarkMoon Yes, connecting a browser from home to a web server in a datacentre. When I use a different ISP, I only change the connection, everything else remains same(The OS, host type). But when using the second ISP, there's change in routes when doing a traceroute.